# Open EDX Android not login

Tags: android, edx, openedx

I have installed an Open EDX Eucalyptus.2. I am preparing the application connection for Android and for IOS.

I have rigorously followed the steps of Github:

File edx.properties in OpenEdXMobile:

```
edx.dir = '../../my_config'
```

In folder my_config:

```
#file edx.properties
edx.android {
    configFiles = ['config.yaml', 'local.yaml']
}
```

-

```
#file local.yaml
OAUTH_CLIENT_ID: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

-

```
#file config.yaml
API_HOST_URL: 'http://my_server/' # localhost is 10.0.2.2 in Android
ENVIRONMENT_DISPLAY_NAME: 'PRO'
PLATFORM_NAME: 'Mooc'
PLATFORM_DESTINATION_NAME: 'my_server'
FEEDBACK_EMAIL_ADDRESS: 'edx@my_server'
```

The app compiles perfectly and starts. The problem is that when I try to login, it does nothing.

In Open EDX everything is set correctly. I have compiled the app for IOS with the same parameters and it works correctly.

Any idea??

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

you should check the following files:

edx / app / edxapp / lms.env.json

edx / app / edxapp / cms.env.json

and make sure they are true

```
"FEATURES": {
     ...
     "ENABLE_MOBILE_REST_API": true,
     "ENABLE_OAUTH2_PROVIDER": true,
     "ENABLE_COMBINED_LOGIN_REGISTRATION": true
}
```

and restart services

for more details see:
http://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/latest/mobile.html